# add to a ntp registry and set default without deleting any other ntp servers

Tags: datetime, windows-7, cmd, registry, ntp

I needed to add an IP into the list of internet time servers in the date and time applet (internet time tab) and set that as the default via command line script. After exhaustive research over honestly a number of years I finally came up with the correct command line.

```
Reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers /v "1" /t REG_SZ /d "192.16.1.2" /f
```

However, there is one issue I face because of this.  This deletes whatever timeserver that was currently "1".  What can I do to prevent this from happening? Cause usually the first entry is time.windows.com which is not something I want to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across this, you can do the following

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d 192.16.1.2 /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers /v 2 /t REG_SZ /d time.windows.com /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers /v 3 /t REG_SZ /d time-b.nist.gov /f
```